# Unable to find stats with Yahoo Fantasy Sports API

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

https://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/game-resource.html

So on the API guide, under stat_categories, there are a set of ids,

https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/game/nba/stat_categories

But when I'm looking at the json data from all the API request I make, there's no

```
{'stats': [{'stat': {'stat_id': 0,
'name': 'Games Played',
'display_name': 'GP',
'sort_order': '1',
'position_types': [{'position_type': 'P'}]}}
```

on it.

This is the result from my json data. As you can see below, there's no stat_id = 0 or 1 or 2. But it starts with 3.

```
'stats': [{'stat': {'stat_id': '3', 'value': '3473'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '4', 'value': '1625'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '6', 'value': '920'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '7', 'value': '713'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '9', 'value': '1069'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '10', 'value': '384'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '12', 'value': '4347'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '13', 'value': '408'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '15', 'value': '1792'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '16', 'value': '1016'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '17', 'value': '271'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '18', 'value': '132'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '19', 'value': '586'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '27', 'value': '63'}},
{'stat': {'stat_id': '28', 'value': '3'}}]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I need the number of Game played everyday to do my analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you query "League Settings", Yahoo will let you know which stats your league tracks for points.  Yahoo will only provide STAT details for stats you're tracking for points.

Most likely, Stat 0 -> Games Played is not a tracked / scoring statistic.  Hence it does not provide you this info when you query players.

The only way to get this stat, is to make your league provide this as a scoring stat.